# Azure IoT hub Partial update of desired properties possible?

Tags: c, azure-iot-hub

is it possible to partially update the reported properties from the device side? So far I only saw articles talking about partially updating the desired properties, like this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins.

If this is possible, is this doable with the azure-iot-hub-c-sdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is doable to update the desired properties with azure-iot-hub-c-sdk. You can refer to the sample ***[iothub_client_sample_device_twin](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_device_twin)***. If you run the sample after modified the *connectionString*, you will get the partial changes from the Azure portal, as following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is documented at [Understand and use device twins in IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins) (retrieved on 2018 Jul 19).

> The device app operates on the device twin using the following atomic operations:
>
> - Retrieve device twin. This operation returns the device twin document (including tags and desired and reported system properties) for the currently connected device.
> - Partially update reported properties. This operation enables the partial update of the reported properties of the currently connected device. This operation uses the same JSON update format that the solution back end uses for a partial update of desired properties.
> - Observe desired properties. The currently connected device can choose to be notified of updates to the desired properties when they happen. The device receives the same form of update (partial or full replacement) executed by the solution back end.

Comment: On the device side node sdk I set up an event listener for the twin on properties.desired.  However, how can I can tell if the this is a partial set or full set, short of a hack (e.g. I can always have a property that's never changed, so if I don't see it, it means it's partial)